# Commutative hash function for password security

Tags: security, authentication, hash, passwords

I had an idea for password security, and am trying to find out if it's already a thing and if so, what I need to do to implement it.

Currently, the password system I'm working on is (simplified, leaving aside stuff like salt):

1. Server stores `hash(password)`
2. User sends plain-text password to server (relying on network security to protect it)
3. Server compares hash of password to stored hash.

My concern is with step 1; either the sent password could be intercepted, or a "fake" server could gather passwords by getting the user to attempt to login. I could improve it slightly by adding an intermediate hash or having the hash take place client-side (so at least someone intercepting communication would only gain access to this server, not others with different hash functions but the same password), but that wouldn't improve the situation for this server.

I was thinking that if I had a pair of commutative hash functions, one of which could be modified with a random key, I could make the process into:

1. Server stores `hash1(password)`
2. When user requests login, server picks a random key and uses it to generate `hash2()`
3. Server sends `hash2()` to user
4. User returns `hash2(password)` to server
5. Server compares `hash1(hash2(password))` to `hash2(hash1(password))`

This way (except for during initial registration), there's no need to rely on a secure network; because hash2 is different every time, even if an attacker intercepted everything sent to the server, they'd be unable to steal any credentials that would let them impersonate the user themselves.

Is this a process that exists, and if so, what's it called? I've been trying to research it, but I'm not sure what it would be called, so I haven't found anything that matches..

If not, is there a better way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Interesting.  How would the user prevent a fake server sending a weak hash2 function, such that the fake server can "unhash" the value sent by step 4 and recover the password?

Comment: I doubth that such a commutative cryptographic hash function can exist, but I suggest that you ask this question at http://security.stackexchange.com/ or even http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @TonyD Hmm... so, the server would be sending specifically a key for a known hash function. If some keys for that hash function were weak/breakable, you'd need some way to check for that. There are also (I believe) ways you could co-agree on a random key (each of you offer a strong hash function and a hash of a random key, then offer the original random key and use the XOR of the two keys.)